# Setting gradle to Android O (API 26)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-8.0-oreo

Android studio has automatically update the following components to API 26:

- ROM - SDK to API 26
- Android SDK Build-Tools 26
- Android Emulator 26.0.3
- Android SDK Platforms-Tools 26.0.0
- Android SDK Tools 26.0.2

My gradle 2.3.3:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 4
        versionName "0.0.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    /////////If I change it to 26.0.0 it gives errors.///////////
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I have two questions (see commented line in Gradle):

How can I know the latest version of these libraries (I simply throw random numbers and try to up them until I found the latest version).

In the excluded group there is 'com.android.support', if I delete that do I need to specify those libraries? I see many people including 'com.android.support' libraries this way so there is a reason I guess to do so.

I searched in developer.android.com and the latest version is 24.2.0 (so really old I have been using 25.3.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use the 26 version you could use the + character at the end of your dependencies.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
```

This way, grade will take the latest version beginning with 26.?.? of your dependency. But you will get a warning from Android Studio, because between two different versions the behavior could eventually change and then produce random effect.

To know the latest version, just take a look here : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

And to finish, if you include 'com.android.support', you will include the whole library. And you certainly not need all the stuff included. If you only use recycler view just add :

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my 2nd question. There is any problem to include the whole library? Like slower compile time?

Comment: Not only slower compile time. You app will be bigger than necessary. Your app will contain useless code and this is a security fail. If you do the same thing with bigger libraries your app size will be a problem. We are not on a desktop application, so mobile developers need to take care of the memory and the CPU use (battery life). Hope it will help :-D

Comment: Are you sure about that? Normally in object oriented languages the .exe (in this case .apk) only compile the libraries that are used (so the assembly code it's the same if you include a useless library). Usually that is the main Linker's job (get libraries, etc into a main file). Why would Android be any different?

Comment: Read the chapter Minimize Resource Use from Libraries in this page : https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html#reduce-resources

Answer (score 0):

Check https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html and set language to English at footer to check latest version of support library. Currently is 25.4.0 (stable) or 26.0.0 (beta 2)

Comment: Thanks m8! Was checking on my native language... There is no stable version so I will wait.

Comment: Actually the stable version is 25.4.0: its just that the page is not updated on other languages. You can update to 25.4.0 without problems

Comment: I understood, but I can't compile that version with API 26 so I will keep API 25 for now.

Comment: Ops sorry, didn't understood you. Yeah, API 26 will force you to use the beta version, so it's better to wait until final release :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting your issue.upcoming 6.0.0 release includes support for Java 8 features, therefore in order to run it (or any of the betas) you need to upgrade your project to include Java 8 support by adding this into you app's gradle file:

```
 compileOptions { 
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```